# Replace characters in WordPress post titles

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to show the title of the current post in a particular way.

Post titles are like:

Balubano 24

Balubano 25

Balubano 26

etc...

I want to only show:

Bal. 24

Bal. 25

Bal. 26

In summary, just replace the characters `ubano` with a `dot`. Balubano 176 becomes Bal. 176

**Note:** I don't want to edit the database, just change how it appears in the template when I call it.

How can I edit the following in order to achieve my goal?

```
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
```

Comment: check for sub-string functions ( substr(), substr_replace(), etc.)

Comment: where are we on this question ? If you received an answer please mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the way titles are displayed by using a filter.

The function you're using, `get_the_title()`, is run through the `the_title` filter.

To modify the output add the following code to your functions.php file:

```
/**
 * Abbreviate 'Balubano' in post titles.
 *
 * @param string $title Post title.
 * @return string
 */
function wpse_filter_post_titles( $title ) {
    return str_replace( 'Balubano', 'Bal.', $title );
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_filter_post_titles' );
```

You can also shorten `echo get_the_title()` to just `the_title()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to add abbreviations in the post 
title.

If the abbreviation list is known, you can use the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function as such:

```
<?php
$abbr=array(
'Balubano'=>'Bal.',
'Street'=>'st.',
'Avenue'=>'av.',
);
echo str_replace(array_keys($abbr),$abbr,get_the_title());
?>
```