# Add line break to WordPress post using a function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a line break to my WordPress post titles.

I only want the line break to appear on the single.php page when it finds this symbol "|" (without quotes) in the title.

[This post](https://medium.com/@clarklab/add-a-line-break-in-a-wordpress-title-b3aeff346037) and others like it here on SO say it can be done by using this inside my template:

```
<?php echo str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title()); ?>
```

But in my case I cannot edit the single.php page directly so I need to add this functionality via some code in the functions.php file.

Do you know what code I should be using?

I tried the code below, but I'm new to this and just hacked it together from what I found online, needless to say it does not work...

```
function line_break_for_posts_filter($title){
  str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title());
  }
add_filter('the_title', 'line_break_for_posts_filter');
```

Comment: I think you have used correct code. please try to see the error by using define('WP_DEBUG',true); in wp-config.php or check from here [Adding A Line Break in The Title](http://webdesignnomad.com/snippets/adding-line-break-br-in-the-title/), [Replace characters in WordPress post titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149931/replace-characters-in-wordpress-post-titles)

Comment: @SunilDora I can't debug it because the code breaks my site completely. It says "Service Unavailable. The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.". I tried adding `return str_replace` but it still has the same problem of crashing the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten to return the filtered result in your `line_break_for_posts_filter` function. Try this:

```
function line_break_for_posts_filter($title){
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        return str_replace(' | ', '<br />', $title);
    } else {
        return str_replace(' | ', '', $title);
    }
}
add_filter('the_title', 'line_break_for_posts_filter');
```

Comment: Still the same problem, it crashes the server.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my answer, the 3rd argument in str_replace() should have just been the variable $title, not the function get_the_title(). The filter already gives us the $title.

Comment: This works! But now I have the problem that it runs everywhere, when I only want it to run on the single.php page. On other pages it should just remove the | symbol. I tried wrapped your function in an IF statement that checks for `is_singular()` but it did not work because the "blog" page that shows a list of posts has no headings. See code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ee1ycdf5/

Comment: Glad it's working for you. I've updated the answer so it checks the page template before running str_replace(). I also used str_replace to remove any more ' | ' symbols from your titles.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't display headings on my blogs page, the page that lists all the recent posts. The headings are missing. Also I think my other code (here: jsfiddle.net/ee1ycdf5) is a bit cleaner by using `is_singular()` instead of `is_page_template('single.php')` becuase it works for all single post types

Comment: Yep you're right about `is_singular()`. I've tested your code (from the JS fiddle above) on a site I'm currently working on and it works perfectly. I think you may have a separate issue. Do you have many other post types or customisations that may be causing a conflict?